# File upload always null, error object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to upload single **.txt** file, and read it's contents. I'm using `IFormFile` to do that. My controller is basically like

```
public IHttpActionResult PostCellInfo(IFormFile file)
{

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {

        var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

and my form in index is

```
  <form name="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="api/CellInfoes">
        <div>
            <input name="file" type="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="upload" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

But error still says

> "ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object."

I think "file" is always `null`. Any ideas why?

I've read that the names must match - but I think this is OK in my code.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct action method in form action attribute. and change your action method parameter to `HttpPostedFileBase` type. and also add [HttpPost] attribute to your post action

Answer (score 0):

The parameter should be `IList<IFormFile> files`.

```
public IHttpActionResult PostCellInfo(IList<IFormFile> files)
{
     foreach (var file in files) {
        if (file.Length > 0) {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {  
               var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
     }
}
```

And change the name attribute in the view also:

```
<form name="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="api/CellInfoes">
        <div>
            <input name="files" type="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="upload" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

I haven't tested this but it should point you in the right direction.
If you want to use `IFormFile` without the collection you should check this [post](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/193).

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick response. Unfortunatelly, nothing changed, While debugging after sending POST request, it still shows "files = null".